# Get Input from User then Use it in a Sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Hello everyone I need your help.
I am running this plain code on atom

```
name =input("What's your name? ")
print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")
age = input("Your age? ")
print("So, you are already " + age + " years old, " + name + "!")
```

it is showing me the sand time icon at the bottom and doesn't give any output.
for other commands like

```
name = "Nick"
print(name)
```

is working perfectly.
I dont know what to do please help.
ptyhon version is 3.6.9

Comment: Hi, its working fine for me (i.e. I see the expected output). Can you share a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: here check this out

Comment: https://postimg.cc/Z05SSV08

Comment: It's waiting for your input.

Comment: no its just freezing

Comment: https://postimg.cc/r0BzF2kz

Comment: its the same issue that others also have https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/2105

Comment: Did you run your code? In Atom I believe the keyboard shortcut is `shift+ctrl+b`